# Let G be a regular graph. Prove that every bridge of G is in every perfect matching of G.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Struggling with a proof for the following:

Let G be a regular graph. Prove that every bridge of G is in every perfect matching of G.

I have ran into this whilst doing some revision work on graph theory.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I am considering a proof by contradiction though I am unsure how to continue from there.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you for your welcome.

I've provided my thoughts on the question and have titled it as the question itself, which is what the quality standards suggest. 

It has tags relating to the context of the question, and I even provided where I think would be a good point to start.

I'm unsure what you're alluding to with my question not following the users' quality standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints.

If the graph is not regular, it is not true.
Take a simple path with four vertices $1,2,3,4$
and three edges $12$, $23$, $34$.
The $23$ edge is a bridge and the $12$, $34$ edges form a  perfect matching.

Let $G$ be a regular graph of degree $d$ and $e=uv$ be a bridge.
Let a perfect matching does not contain edge $e$.

Then graph $G-e$ has two components $G_1$ and $G_2$ ($u\in V(G_1)$ and $v\in V(G_2)$) and
the number of vertices of each component is even. (why?)

On the other hand, by the handshaking lemma we have for the graph $G_1$
$$
2|E(G_1)|=\sum_{x\in V(G_1)}\operatorname{deg}(x)=d(|V(G_1)|-1)+(d-1)=d|V(G_1)|-1.\ (\rm why?)
$$
Contradiction.

Comment: I'm unsure as to why the number of vertices is even in the components and how this leads to a contradiction. I apologise for my unfamiliarity but if you could please provide some further hints as I would love to learn how this is so.

Comment: Why is the number of vertices in each component even?
Our perfect matching has no edges connecting vertices $G_1$ and $G_2$. So each of its edges lies in $G_1$ or $G_2$. That is, $G_1$ (and $G_2$) has a perfect matching. I hope you understand that a graph with perfect matching has even number of vertices.

Comment: Ah I see! Yes, I understand why a perfect matching has an even number of vertices. This makes a lot sense. Appreciate the help!